# Azure AD guest users encountering double MFA

Tags: azure, multi-factor-authentication, azure-ad-b2b, microsoft365

I have Azure [security defaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults) enabled for my organization. I have several external guest users who are part of another organization that also enforces MFA.

Guest users are reporting that they are being forced to go through two stages of MFA when signing in to access my organization's resources - one from their home organization and a second one from my own organization.

Is this expected behaviour? It doesn't make sense to me that guest users would need to provide two separate MFA credentials to authenticate on an external organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed expected behavior currently. But I agree that double MFA is not logically user-friendly.

In this case, it is reasonable for the guest users to experience their own tenant's MFA only once. Unfortunately Microsoft does not support that currently.

It's recommended to vote up [a similar user voice post](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/37590304-b2b-scenario-the-b2b-guest-user-should-use-the-m).

A [similar issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/44699) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for the info. It's a bit concerning that this issue has been reported as far back as December 2019 but still nothing has been done about it..